# SCP is not working but just showing the usage

Tags: ssh, scp

```
scp -r /Users/localusername/Desktop/test hostname@ipaddress/Users/hostname/Desktop
usage: scp [-346BCpqrTv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
            [-J destination] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port]      
            [-S program] source ... target
```

I try to upload a folder called “test” from a local PC to the host PC using SCP via ssh, but it always shows the usage without transferring the folder. Can anyone let me know how to fix the problem?

Comment: There needs to be a `:` between the ipaddress and file path

Comment: `scp -r /Users/localusername/Desktop/test hostname@ipaddress:/Users/hostname/Desktop`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but still, it shows the usage stuff with the ":".